# clang failed exit with code 1

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I am just copying application in xcode 4.2.App was created in xcode 4.5 .

I got this error when i compile it on my older mac machine.

[image: Error Massage]

Please Help Me.

Thanks.

Comment: Google your question before asking here! You may find your answer in some of  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560239/xcode-command-developer-usr-bin-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907112/command-developer-usr-bin-clang-failed-with-exit-code-1), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378139/clang-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-building-archive-works-when-building-debug), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127688/clang-failed-with-exit-code-1) answers.

Comment: @Hemang i had tried a lot with google and stackoverflow but can't solve this error so i put it here.

Comment: It says exactly what the problem is in the error.

Comment: @Abizern ya,i knew it. i can see. but how to solve this error?

Comment: By either making sure the file exists where the project thinks it exists, or removing it from your build settings.

Answer (score 2):

It’s looking for a prefix header file. Did you delete it? If so, then you should delete the Prefix Header setting in the Build Settings tab of the project editor.